# create in pandas matrix rfm

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I'm calculating a rfv table in pandas, but im not able to find a tutorial or post that helps me building the matrix necessary for the graph.
[The graph i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs2Kc.png) using [this base from matplot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/table_demo.html)
each square being the count of clients in that position.

The dataframe im using now has this columns:

| COD_CLIENT | RECENCY | FRE_VAL | R | FV | RFV | RFV_Score | RFV_Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 59 | 87 | 45.45 | 3 | 3 | 33 | 6 | Potential |
| 1846 | 75 | 6.00 | 3 | 2 | 32 | 5 | Seleepers |
| 4380 | 92 | 37.95 | 2 | 3 | 23 | 5 | Seleepers |
| **object** | **int64** | **float64** | **int32** | **int32** | **int32** | **int64** | **object** |

What do you guys sugest i do?
I already tried using R and FV as columns and rows and using a function but this went badly.

Comment: Seems like you first need to count the number of clientes per R/FV pair, try using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` and then using `.size()` to get the number of rows per group. Like this: `df.groupby(["R", "FV"]).size()`. Does this work as you expect?

Comment: Thank you. This was exactally what i was looking for. Using df.unstack to turn it again into a table will do perfectly the work. Really thank you, it took the last 3 days searching this.

Comment: FTR, I just added my comment as an answer, in case you want to add any comment or mark is as a solution, @Ricardo Santos . Happy to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to count the number of rows for each (R, FV) pair, so you could try using [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas-dataframe-groupby) and then counting the number of elements in each group by using [`.size()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size) on the previous result. The resulting code should look like this:

```
import pandas as pd


>> df = ...  # Assuming your DataFrame has the format you showed

>> df.groupby(["R", "FV"]).size()
R  FV
1  1     2
   2     1
   3     1
2  1     1
   2     1
dtype: int64

>> df.groupby(["R", "FV"]).size().unstack()  # Add unstack to format the result
FV    1    2    3
R                
1   2.0  1.0  1.0
2   1.0  1.0  NaN
```

This should match your expected output.